# Non-Consumable In-App Purchase Build Rejected

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I got two Non-Consumable in-app purchases in my app and I submitted the build for review yesterday and it got rejected, this is what Apple mentioned:

[image]

What I've tested?:
I tested the in-app purchase using a Sandbox account, it processes just fine.
But when i use my actual apple id in the sandbox account, this is what's happening:
[image]

And this is status i get:

`func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])`

I get `Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"`

Comment: What is your question?  ¿Cuál es tu pregunta?  質問は何なの？

Comment: @El Tomato the question is why I get the error when I use the actual Apple ID for sandbox (this is what apple asked for).

Comment: What is your definition of an 'actual apple id in the sandbox account'?

Comment: The one that’s not a sandbox account, the one you can use in the App Store.

Comment: What makes you think that you could make a purchase with an actual account over an unpublished app?

Comment: Read the ‘next step’ mentioned in the Guideline 2.1,

Comment: All right.  I've read 'Next steps,' not next step.  And then what!?

Comment: Please don’t comment here again.

Comment: Have you figured out why they reject? I'm having similar issue. Did Apple attach any screenshot of the error message?

Comment: @TrongNguyen I did figure it out. Not sure but I think I provided the review team the Sandbox login.